# Laravel relation belongsTo error Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Tags: laravel

I'm getting the error Trying to get property 'name' of non-object when trying to print in my view the attribute name of a `belongsTo` relationship made to the entity (model) Institution, the funniest thing is that I did the same thing with the user relationship and it worked.

I have tried several resolutions that have in the stack overflow but none of them got results, seems to be simple thing, but ... don't work

**Model Institution**

```php
class Institution extends Model implements Transformable
{

    use TransformableTrait;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public $timestamps = true;
}
```

**Model User**

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = [
        'cpf',
        'name',
        'phone',
        'birth',
        'gender',
        'notes',
        'email',
        'password',
        'status',
        'permission'
    ];
```

**Group Entity**

```php
class Group extends Model implements Transformable
{
    use TransformableTrait;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name','user_id','institution_id'];

    // a classe grupo pertence ao usuario atraves do metodo owneruser e institution
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function institution()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Institution::class);
    }

}
```

**GroupsController**

```php
    public function index()
    {

        $groups = $this->repository->all();
        $user_list = $this->userRepository->selectBoxList();
        $institution_list = $this->institutionRepository->selectBoxList();

        return view('group.index', [
            'groups' => $groups,
            'user_list' => $user_list,
            'institution_list' => $institution_list
        ]);
    }
```

**View Group**

```php
@foreach($groups as $group)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $group->id }} </td>
    <td>{{ $group->name }} </td>

    // In this line where the error
    // Trying to get property 'name' of non-object  occurs
    <td> {{$group->institution->name }} </td>
    // This line is working
    <td> {{ $group->user->name }} </td>

    <td>
        {!! Form::open(['route' => ['group.destroy', $group->id], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
            {!! Form::submit("Remover") !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I hope the output in `<td>{{ $group-> institution-> name }}</ td>`
Be the name of the institution in which the group is associated through the foreign key, instead it returns the error.

Comment: One of the reasons I can think of is that `institution` of `group` is null. can you check the database that all the rows in the `groups` table has saved the `institution_id`?

Comment: @TharakaDilshan  
Hello, thanks for replying, I checked the database and all groups are with institution_id filled in, look:  [link](https://pasteboard.co/IcCN8sh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the DB image I see that you are using uppercase for your foreign key `Institution_id` while using it lowercase elsewhere. I believe it is case-sensitive, so try this in your `Group` model:

```
public function institution()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Institution::class, 'Institution_id');
}
```

And change it in the `fillable` list as well.

Comment: that's right! It worked, thank you very much, I had not paid attention to this, thank you very much.